# L'hopital's Rule in higher dimensions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was working on getting intuition behind limits in multivariate calculus and I ran into this [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.0363.pdf).

I am mostly concerned with the case where we have functions of two or three variables. Unfortunately I do not have the necessary background to understand the proof provided but I think that if the partial derivative in a given direction is not zero in the neighborhood of the limit point (for which the numerator and denominator are zero) then we have:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}=\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (a,b)} \frac{D_vf(x,y)}{D_vg(x,y)}$$

So when seeking to resolve a question about limits (when the numerator and denominator are both zero at the point), I should quickly check the partial derivative of the numerator and denominator in convenient directions and ensure that they do not both vanish in the neighborhood. Is this a correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the limit of the quotient exists AND the partial derivatives exist in a neighborhood AND the limit of the partial derivatives exists, then you can find the limit by the procedure you describe. Because then everything reduces to the one-dimensional case by 
$$\tilde{f}(t):=f((x,y)+tv)\quad 
\tilde{g}(t):=g((x,y)+tv).$$

However, for $f(x,y)=x+y$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+y$ the limit of $f/g$ doesn't exist if $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, although taking the directional derivative in the $v=(0,1)$ direction would yield a result $1$.